# jsonpath: mix two paths

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jsonpath

I am querying facebook for fullsize profilepictures of users that commented on posted pictures or who like posted pictures by the /me user, using the graph api.
I am trying to either:

- do it in one query, where i am having trouble getting data from deep enough.
- or minimize the amount of subqueries

In one query: this does not work (it does not give details of the users that commented):

```
me/photos/uploaded?fields=from,images,comments.picture,likes.picture&limit=500
```

and specifying the dimensions throws an error:

```
me/photos/uploaded?fields=from,images,comments.picture,likes.picture.type(large)&limit=500
```

There seems to be a limit as to how deep you can specify, though I havent found anything explicit in the documentation. (which is so terse that is hardly a big surprise)

so, resolving to batched queries with a dependency

```
myphotos => me/photos/uploaded?fields=created_time,name,id,from,comments.summary(1).limit(100),images,likes.summary(1).limit(100)&limit=500 
userinfo_photocomments => ?ids={result=myphotos:$.data.*.comments.data.*.from.id}&fields=id,name,updated_time,picture.redirect(0).type(large).height(2000).width(2000)
userinfo_photolikes => ?ids={result=myphotos:$.data.*.likes.data.*.id}&fields=id,name,updated_time,picture.redirect(0).type(large).height(2000).width(2000)
```

though this works, the fact that i cant find how to do it in one or max 2 queries annoys me, especially as the results of the last 2 subqueries will most likely overlap.

I would like to find a way to mix the jsonpath anchors, such that i can combine the last two queries.
The problem seems to be that the userid's of the commentors and the likers are on different depths in the trees.

I would be gratefull for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the result from the first query twice, resulting in only two queries.

I tested the `?ids=` endpoint if it filters out duplicate `user_id` like the following:

```
GET /?ids={user_id1},{user_id2},{user_id1}
```

which results in only getting two distinct `user_ids` back.

So, this yields in the following batch query:

```
curl \
   -F 'access_token={access_token}' \
   -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"myphotos","relative_url":"me/photos/uploaded?fields=created_time,name,id,from,comments.summary(1).limit(100),images,likes.summary(1).limit(100)&limit=500",},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=myphotos:$.data.*.comments.data.*.from.id},{result=myphotos:$.data.*.likes.data.*.id}&fields=id,name,updated_time,picture.redirect(0).type(large).height(2000).width(2000)"}]' \
   https://graph.facebook.com/
```

Just replace `{access_token}` with an actual access token to test this.

Basically, I just concatenated the `user_id` lists for comments and likes as

```
GET ?ids={result=myphotos:$.data.*.comments.data.*.from.id},{result=myphotos:$.data.*.likes.data.*.id}&fields=...
```

Comment: That is a very practical way indeed.
Solved it as such that it is brought down to 2 queries. Good thinking!

Comment: Glad that it works for you. Good thing is also that FB makes the `user_ids` distinct, and you don't have to filter those yourself.

Comment: Well, there is another a catch: if there are many pictures comming from the first query, then there will be pagination. And because of that the IDs will overlap in the joined result pages...

Comment: ... Which is something i had to solve programmatically at the end.